# Rally ObjectID clarifications

Tags: web-services, rally, appsdk2

2 clarifications needed for ObjectID fields:

1) Are ObjectID's globally unique across a subscription or across all of Rally's subscriptions?

2) Are The ObjectID's of built in Rally things constants and the exact same for all subscriptions? For example, in one of my workspaces, to get the allowed ScheduleState values for a UserStory, i have to hit this endpoint:

```
    /AttributeDefinition/-41562/AllowedValues
```

where -41562 is the ObjectID. Can I assume that every other subscription uses -41562 for the ObjectID in this URL to get the valid Schedule States?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) ObjectID's are unique per stack.  So all of the ObjectID's on the SaaS stack (rally1.rallydev.com) are unique.

2) ObjectID's that are negative like the ScheduleState one mentioned above will be the same across workspaces.  However things like custom fields and portfolioitem type and attributes will have unique ObjectID's across different workspaces.

Are you wanting to cache these values for perf reasons or what is it you're looking to do with them?

Comment: Ok thanks. i ask because i need to get the possible ScheduleState values for a User Story, and I can't figure out how to get them using a wsapi query, without using the hardcoded negative ObjectID. If other people in other subscriptions or workspaces are going to use this app, I want to make sure the hardcoded value is the same (or a workaround that doesn't involve a hardcoded OID

Comment: Check out the example for dynamically looking up allowed values for fields in this guide: http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/collections_in_v2-section-collection-fetching

Comment: ok. the example in your link was sufficient. however, itd be nice to be able (to know how) to do all this purely using wsapi queries.

Comment: The code in the guide basically makes the wsapi query you had originally.  For built-in fields like ScheduleState this is always the same negative oid.  For other fields like custom fields or fields on dynamic types like portfolioitems the oids will be different, so it's usually easier to use the allowedvaluestores.